# iOS MPMoviePlayerViewController only works on debug not in final

Tags: ios, objective-c, debugging, mpmovieplayercontroller, testflight

I implemented a `MPMoviePlayerViewController`like this:

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface ViewController : UITableViewController
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"


@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

/* SOME CODE AND A TAPGESTURERECOGNIZER */
/* CALLS [self playVideo] */

-(void) playVideo{

    @try {

        NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"myGeneratedURL"];
        NSLog(@"URL: %@",URL);
        MPMoviePlayerViewController *video = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]
                                          initWithContentURL:URL];

        [self.navigationController presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:video];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {

    }

}
```

So now my problem is that it works just fine on both simulator and on my iphone (if i debug it), but when i upload a build to itunesconnect and download it via TestFlight the `MPMoviePlayerViewController` does not show up. The URL in `NSLog` is definitely the same in all three cases ( sim , iphone debug, testflight ).
I don't know where i should start searching the error...

Comment: are you playing a video from documents directory or web?.

Comment: i am playing it from the web

Comment: I would suggest you use a strong property of `MPMoviePlayerViewController` rather than local instance

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using strong reference rather than an local variable.

You can follow [this tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/video-recording-playback-ios-programming/)